# iBrowser - downloading ibrowser.php instead of popping up the window

Tags: python, django, apache, tinymce

At first I need to say, that I'm very new to all those a-little-bit-upper programming and web-things.

Ok, I recived a task from my boss to put some easy image-tool in TinyMCE (used in Django) on one of our customer's site.

I tried some plugins (like Filebrowser), but none of them was working correctly (maybe Django version here is not compatibile... oh, nevermind).

**[ The problem ]**
So I've put iBrowser into TinyMCE, I have the right icon in TinyMCE, but when i click it - at first some new window is loading, but then window closes and Firefox ask me if i prefer to view or download "ibrowser.php" file...
**[/ The problem ]**

I've search a bit and I've found, that the problem could be in Apache, that I should configure something there. But... i don't know really WHERE and HOW...

I've found those two questions, that probably could help me a bit:

[question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591650/browser-downloads-php-file-from-apache-web-server)

[question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245895/apache2-on-ubuntu-php-files-downloading)

but in my project's folder there are no files like "php5.conf" or even "*.conf".

So... please help?

I can of course put here some lines from my code, just tell me what You want :)

Comment: You should use a Python based solution. Filebrowser for instance. If you want to use iBrowser you would have to install PHP alongside Python. That's not desirable in my mind. But if you really have to use iBrowser you don't find php5.conf in your Django project. Depending on your operating system and several other things you find those configs in different places. So you should tell us what operating system you are using. Google for help on tinymce + filebrowser + django: https://www.google.de/?q=tinymce%20%2B%20filebrowser%20%2B%20django

Comment: Hi, thx for Your reply :)
My system is Ubuntu 12.04.
And well I also decided to use FileBrowser anyway. Looks like it wasn't working because my Django and TinyMCE versions was not compatibile to grappelli...
But, so... for the future - can You tell me (if You know) where can I find those "php5.conf" on my Ubuntu 12.04?
And probably even if I'll make it work on my localhost, I'll need to do something more, when I'll push my project onto a server, right?

Comment: Your php.conf is mostly likely under "/etc/php5/" and its subdirectories. If you have php installed, that is. And if you want to use it on your server you will also have to do a little bit of configuration.