# Local Apache server doesn't run php file, instead the web browser downloads

Tags: apache, apache2

My local Apache server doesn't run my php file, instead the web browser downloads it when I try to view it. I'm using LAMP on Ubuntu. Would you help me how I can solve this problem? Thank!

Comment: possible duplicate of [browser downloads php file from apache web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591650/browser-downloads-php-file-from-apache-web-server)

Comment: Problem solved, here is what I have done: I put back all my php file into the default html directory then I assigned DocumentRout variable to /bar/www/html/. DocmentRout variable is located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file. Thanks for all !

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell LAMP to handle `.php` files with the `php5_module`?

Check your current php setting by creating a new php file in the `htdocs` or `www` direectory with the following content:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

This will show you if your webserver can process php files or not